# Showing an objects coordinates on stage with AS3..?

Tags: actionscript-3, coordinates

I am completely new to ActionScript so please understand that I do not know where to begin with this.

I need to show a an objects coordinates on stage as it moves across the screen.

Any help is much appreciated!

thanks,
Alex

Comment: Do you mean visually see text by your object, or do you mean you need to see debug trace statements of the object?

Comment: yes, to visually see what the coordinates of the object are as it moves, shown in a text field that updates frame by frame. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach, you could of course get more detailed with it, for instance check that a value has changed ( i.e. the object is moving ) before updating the TextField text value. You could even use two TextFields, one for the x position, the other for the y.

You may use another type of event listener , it would depend on what makes your object move...

```
var object:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var textfield:TextField = new TextField();

object.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME , positionListener );

function positionListener( event:Event ):void
{
   textfield.text = "x:" + object.x.toString() + "| y:" + object.y.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please note that I just showed the bare minimum, for this to work you need to add the children! Since you're new to AS3, I thought I 'd mention that...

Answer (score 0):

thanks!

solution:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, show);
function show(evt:Event):void{
  coords_txt.text = object1.x+" - "+object1.y
}
```